# Bind Function to Allow Added Buttons to Function Correctly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bind

So I have a table with two separate buttons, Edit and Deactivate. I was able to use a bind function on the deactivate in order to the button to work when i added rows. However, I can't seem to figure out the edit button. I think that I have copied most of the information correctly from my other bind function, but have seen no success yet. Was hoping someone may be able to offer up some help. I am just needing the Edit button to work and function correctly when additional rows are added to the table.

HTML/PHP:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stage Rebate Master HTML Table</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="html_master.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="html_master.js"></script>
    </head>

<label id="table_name">Stage_Rebate_Master</label><br>

<body>

<img src="carter.png" alt="Carter Lumber" id="carter">

<table id="html_master">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ID</td>
    <td>Vendor</td>
    <td>Buyer ID</td>
    <td>POC Name</td>
    <td>POC Email</td>
    <td>POC Phone</td>
    <td>Edit/Delete</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $rows){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="mr_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo intval ($rows['MR_ID'])?></td>
        <td class="mr_name" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_Name']?></td>
        <td class="buyer_id" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['Buyer_ID']?></td>
        <td class="poc_n" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_N']?></td>     
        <td class="poc_e" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_E']?></td>
        <td class="poc_p" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $rows['MR_POC_P']?></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
        <input type="button" class="deactivate" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate"></td>
    </tr>
 <?php
  }
 ?>
</tbody>
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
</table>

<input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// ----- Deactivate Row -----

function bindDeactivate() {
  $('#html_master').on("click",".deactivate",function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
    var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
      $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
      $this.val(function(i, t) {
        return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
      });
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the deactivate button click to the function
    bindDeactivate();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind the edit button click to the function
    bindEdit();
});

// ----- Add Row -----

function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "text";
    element3.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type = "text";
    element4.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("input");
    element5.type = "text";
    element5.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("input");
    element6.type = "text";
    element6.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell6.appendChild(element6);

    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
    var element7 = document.createElement("input");
    var element8 = document.createElement("input");
    element7.type = "button";
    element8.type = "button";
    element7.name="edit";
    element8.name="deactivate";

    var setClass = document.createAttribute("class");
    setClass.value = "edit";
    element7.setAttributeNode(setClass);

    var setClass1 = document.createAttribute("class");
    setClass1.value = "deactivate";
    element8.setAttributeNode(setClass1);

    element7.attr="class";
    element8.attr="class";
    element7.value="Edit";
    element8.value="Deactivate";
    cell7.appendChild(element7);
    cell7.appendChild(element8);

    // Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
    $('#html_master').off("click",'.deactivate');
    bindDeactivate();

    // Bind this new deactivate button click to the function
    $('#html_master').off("click",'.edit');
    bindEdit();
}




function bindEdit() {
    $('#html_master').on("click",".edit",function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
    });
    if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
        $this.html('Save');
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
    } else {
        var isValid = true;
        var errors = '';
        $('#myDialogBox').empty();
        tds.each(function(){
             var type = $(this).attr('class');
             var value = $(this).text();
             switch(type){
                 case "buyer_id":
                     if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                         isValid = false;
                         errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
                      }
                     break;
                case "poc_n":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_e":
                    if(value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
                    }
                    break;
                case "poc_p":
                    if(value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')){
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        isValid = false;
                        errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";    
                    }
                    break;
             }
        })
        if(isValid){
            $this.html('Edit');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
        }else{
            alert(errors);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell2.appendChild(element2);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("input");
        element3.type = "text";
        element3.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element3);

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var element4 = document.createElement("input");
        element4.type = "text";
        element4.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell4.appendChild(element4);

        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        var element5 = document.createElement("input");
        element5.type = "text";
        element5.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell5.appendChild(element5);

        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        var element6 = document.createElement("input");
        element6.type = "text";
        element6.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell6.appendChild(element6);

        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        var element7 = document.createElement("input");
        var element8 = document.createElement("input");
        element7.type = "button";
        element7.setAttribute("class","edit");
        element8.setAttribute("class","deactivate");
        element8.type = "button";
        element7.name="edit";
        element8.name="deactivate";
        element7.value="Edit";
        element8.value="Deactivate";
        cell7.appendChild(element7);
        cell7.appendChild(element8);
    }

    $(document).on('click','.deactivate',function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
        var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
          $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
          $this.text(function(i, t) {
            return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
          });
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click','.edit',function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function() {
            return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
        });
        if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
            $this.html('Save');
            tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
        } else {
            var isValid = true;
            var errors = '';
            $('#myDialogBox').empty();
            tds.each(function(){
                 var type = $(this).attr('class');
                 var value = $(this).text();
                 switch(type){
                     case "buyer_id":
                         if(!$.isNumeric(value)){
                             isValid = false;
                             errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
                          }
                         break;
                    case "poc_n":
                        if(value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)){
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            isValid = false;
                            errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
                        }
                        break;
                    case "poc_e":
                        if(value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)){
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            isValid = false;
                            errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
                        }
                        break;
                    case "poc_p":
                        if(value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')){
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            isValid = false;
                            errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";    
                        }
                        break;
                 }
            })
            if(isValid){
                $this.html('Edit');
                tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
            }else{
                alert(errors);
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="html_master">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Vendor</td>
        <td>Buyer ID</td>
        <td>POC Name</td>
        <td>POC Email</td>
        <td>POC Phone</td>
        <td>Edit/Delete</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
            <br>
            <input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('html_master')">
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```